# Preserving changes to standard ROS packages

Tags: ros, archlinux, compilation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Archlinux, kernel 2.6.39-ARCH
gcc version 4.6.1

In order to compile some packages, I need to patch certain source codes and make changes to CMakeList.txt...

How do I preserve these changes so that when I update ROS by:

```
$ rosinstall ~/ros
```

... I don't have to re-make the changes again.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10578/preserving-changes-to-standard-ros-packages/) by [DavidS](https://answers.ros.org/users/813/davids/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2011-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you update your source based ROS installation it won't overwrite your changes, at worst you would have to merge the changed files manually if there are any conflicts (see [rosinstall](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosinstall#Local_changes_protections) documentation). But things like CMakeList doesn't change very often. Another thing to do is submit patches to package maintainers, so that your changes can be integrated and whenever next version is released it  will just work out of the box.

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2011-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4